# Android using dagger2 for create viewpager adapter not showing fragments after recreate activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, dagger-2

I have a viewpager in my MainActivity that adds 10 fragments in its adapter.
I create a dagger module that provides a singletone viewpager adapter.

```
@Module
class FragmentModule(val fm : FragmentManager) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getViewPagerAdapter() : MainViewPagerAdapter {
        val adapter = MainViewPagerAdapter(fm)
        val categoryList : ArrayList<CategoryModel> = MyDataBase.getCategoryList()
        for (item in categoryList ) {
            val fragment = MainFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable(Options.bundle_catModel, item)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            adapter.addFragment(fragment, item.name)
        }
        return adapter
    }

}
```

and inject this adapter to MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), MainView { 
   .
   .
   .
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentsAdapter: MainViewPagerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       App.getComponent(supportFragmentManager).inject(this) //pass supportFragmentManager to FragmentModule as parameter

       viewpager.apply {
           this.adapter = fragmentsAdapter
           tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(this)
         }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

When I recreate activity to change theme, my viewpager not showing fragments.
I have checked that my fragments creates, my viewPager visibility is visible and viewPager height not equals to 0. But it will not be displayed!
Does anyone know where the problem is?